# Fetch API not sending session cookies when used inside a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, cors, csrf, fetch-api

I'm trying to make a Chrome Extension which scrapes some details from Pull Requests on Github using the Fetch API, and then displays them elsewhere. I'm running into some problems when I try to use this with a non-public repository on Github. I believe this is related to CSRF protection, and the rules that govern Chrome extensions having access to session cookies.

I have the following in my extension's `manifest.json`:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [
        "*://github.com/*/*/pulls"
    ],
    "js": ["script/underscore-1.8.3.min.js", "script/content.js"]
}],
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "*://github.com/*",
    "webNavigation"
]
```

But when I run the following from within my `script/content.js`:

```
fetch('/redacted/redacted/pull/4549', {credentials: 'same-origin'}).then((response) => {
    return response.text();
}).then((text) => {
    // do cool stuff
})
```

This produces a 404 response from Github. Inspecting this request with Chrome Inspector's network tab, I can see it is not sending my GitHub session header with the request.

If I make the very same request using the Javascript prompt in the Inspector, I can see a 200 response, and I can see that it *is* sending my session cookies.

My understanding was that specifying the Github domain in my `manifest.json` would mean my extension would have access to my session data in my content scripts, is this not correct? What should I be doing to make a valid request to this protected content?

Comment: I have this issue as well, fetch simply don't send cookies even with `credentials: 'same-origin'`, while XHR just send everything, seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Chrome blog](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch#sending-credentials-with-a-fetch-request), to include cookies you need `credentials: 'include'` instead of `credentials: 'same-origin'`.

Comment: While using `credentials: 'include'` is indeed the correct solution, the blog post you cite in no way backs you up; it doesn't even *mention* Chrome extensions or `credentials: 'same-origin'` (which *is* a valid option in the `init` parameter of a `fetch()` call, but just won't work in the context of a Chrome extension). The real reason you need `credentials: 'include'` is that Chrome extensions execute in a notional window whose URL is on the `chrome-extension://` scheme, and therefore definitely not on the *same origin* as any real domain you might want to make a fetch request to.

Comment: I'm still not able to send the cookies even after setting `credentials: 'include'`. I've read tons of SO questions, but to no luck.

Comment: I have the same problem while doing this from a Chrome extension. It works with the same Firefox extension, so I am fairly sure that all CORS-Headers are set correctly. @PythonEnthusiast, did you meanwhile find a solution for this?

Comment: any luck with the solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. `"permissions"` in manifest may contain only known permission strings. In order to let it call GitHub, use `"host_permissions"` instead:

```
...
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "webNavigation"
],
"host_permissions: [
    "*://github.com/*",
]
```

2. `'same-origin'` is the default value for `credentials` property, it can be omitted. This value restricts sending cookies and authentication HTTP headers to domains other than the calling script origin. Chrome extension origin looks like `chrome-extension://abcxyz..` and won't send even GitHub cookies to the GitHub. Instead you need `credentials: 'include'`.
   *This is true for an extension that overrides a Chrome URL, not sure about others*.

Answer (score -3):

Specifying github in the permissions only gives access to the host, its there to limit damage if the extension/app is compromised by malware ([source](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions)).

Its not indicated in the [content script documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) that session data can be retrieved in content scripts, just their DOMs. I think it would be better if you use and incorporate the official Github API in the chrome extension project you're creating.